# Routing issue in React with Webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, routes

I routed in my app as the following:

```
render(
  <Provider store={store}>
      <Router history={browserHistory }>
        <Route path={"/" component={TopContainer}>
            <IndexRoute component={Login} />
            <Route path='main' component={Maintainer} />    
        </Route>
    </Router>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Then I deploy my production bundle.js and index.html directly under my web root (apache in ubuntu).
I can access my app at http://...com/
The problem is that after the main page is loaded with route

```
<Route path='main' component={Maintainer} />
```

the content in browser location becomes: http://...com/main

At this time, if I reload the page with the url (http://...com/main) I got a page not found error: "The requested URL /main was not found on this server."

Here the my webpack.production.config.js

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');
var loaders = require('./webpack.loaders');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var WebpackCleanupPlugin = require('webpack-cleanup-plugin');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

loaders.push({
  test: /\.scss$/,
  loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({fallback: 'style-loader', use : 'css-loader?sourceMap&localIdentName=[local]___[hash:base64:5]!sass-loader?outputStyle=expanded'}),
  exclude: ['node_modules']
});

module.exports = {
  entry: [
    './src/index.js'
  ],
  output: {
    publicPath: './',       
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
    filename: '[chunkhash].js'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
  },
  module: {
    loaders
  },
  plugins: [
    new WebpackCleanupPlugin(),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: '"production"'
      }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compress: {
        warnings: false,
        screw_ie8: true,
        drop_console: true,
        drop_debugger: true
      }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
    new ExtractTextPlugin({
      filename: 'style.css',
      allChunks: true
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './index.html',
      files: {
        css: ['style.css'],
        js: ['bundle.js'],
      }
    })
  ]
};
```

But if I run it on the local server, there is not such a problem:

```
"use strict";
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');
var loaders = require('./webpack.loaders');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var DashboardPlugin = require('webpack-dashboard/plugin');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

const HOST = process.env.HOST || "127.0.0.1";
const PORT = process.env.PORT || "3000";

loaders.push({
  test: /\.scss$/,
  loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader?importLoaders=1', 'sass-loader'],
  exclude: ['node_modules']
});

module.exports = {
  entry: [
    'react-hot-loader/patch',
    './src/index.js', // your app's entry point
  ],
  devtool: process.env.WEBPACK_DEVTOOL || 'eval-source-map',
  output: {
    publicPath: '/',
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
  },
  module: {
    loaders
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: "./public",
    // do not print bundle build stats
    noInfo: true,
    // enable HMR
    hot: true,
    // embed the webpack-dev-server runtime into the bundle
    inline: true,
    // serve index.html in place of 404 responses to allow HTML5 history
    historyApiFallback: true,
    port: PORT,
    host: HOST
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new ExtractTextPlugin({
      filename: 'style.css',
      allChunks: true
    }),
    new DashboardPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './index.html',
      files: {
        css: ['style.css'],
        js: [ "bundle.js"],
      }
    }),
  ]
};
```

I also tried it on a node.js web server and got the same problem.

Is the contentBase: "./public" made it?

thanks

coolshare

Comment: It looks like your webpack/routing config is correct. Especially if you say it works in dev.
My guess would be that your server side needs to route all urls (except maybe the static/assets folder?) to your `index.html` so then `react-router` takes over the routing.

Comment: contentBase is just where webpack dev server will find static files from such as images etc

The issue appears to be that while webpack dev server will handle url mapping for you automagically locally, your production server doesn't have this luxury and you will still need to let it know how and where to serve files from using `.htaccess`/`nginx.conf` etc depending upon what server you use in prod

Under the surface it uses pushstate rather than normal url routing, so you will need your server to direct all urls to your index page, where the JS can pick it up and do its own routing

Comment: Sorry I can't seem to be able to edit my comment on Firefox...

Here is a link that could help you to config your apache server to redirect everything (except static files) to your `index.html` so the Javascript can manage its own routing.
https://gkedge.gitbooks.io/react-router-in-the-real/content/apache.html

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. What I want to the internal routing correctly. "route all urls (except maybe the static/assets folder?) to your index.html " is not what I want. That is, http://...com/ to go to my login page while http://...com/main should go to my main page and http://...com/second should be routed to my second page...

Comment: Yes Mark... but what we say is that you have two different routings. The one done by JS/React-router which seems to work in your "local case" and the one done by Apache on the server side.

The server side routing is happening before the client side one.
Which means when you go to ...com/main the server router doesn't know this URL and throws a 404 error.
If you route this URL to your index.html then the JS router will activate and display the correct page.

Comment: Vincent, thanks for your response and the first part of your answer is correct. see my post below.

Answer (score 0):

With Vincent's suggestion, I added some redirects to my Apache config

```
    DocumentRoot /var/www

    Redirect permanent /main http://...com/
```

This work partially: Apache did route http://...com/main to http://...com/

The problem is that from then on React takes over but it routes it to the login screen instead of what I expected - stay in the current screen http://...com/main when reload the browser page.

 "If you route this URL to your index.html then the JS router will activate and display the correct page." is not true: I tried

```
Redirect permanent /main http://...com/index.html
```

and Apache did not recognize the http://...com/index.html

But Apache 

It seems no way to route it to the main page...